# Why am I getting an error using std::locale::locale(const std::string&)?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm getting the following error when using the constructor of `std::locale`:

> error: no matching function for call to `‘std::locale::locale(std::string&)’`

Here is the program:

> ```
> #include <string>
> #include <locale>
>
> int main()
> {
>     std::string str = "en_US.UTF8";
>     std::locale loc = std::locale(str);
> }
> ```

It's strange because in the documentation it clearly shows the overloaded constructor:

> ```
> explicit locale( const std::string& );
> ```

I'm getting different but similar errors on the latest versions of GCC and Clang. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems libstdc++ isn't updated to accept a `std::string` as argument (libc++ is updated). For C++03 there was no constructor taking a `std::string`. Just use

```
std::locale loc(str.c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

The current implementation of libstdc++ doesn't support the `const std::string&` constructor for `std::locale`.